# Consuming api from django rest framework

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I have used django rest api to create an api that looks like this -

```
{
"count": 2,
"next": null,
"previous": null,
"results": [
    {
        "url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/app/student/1/",
        "id": 1,
        "title": "mr",
        "name": "student1",
        "address": "somewhere",
        "city": "Mumbai",
        "tests": [
            {
                "test_name": "Math",
                "section_1": "34",
                "section_2": "54",
                "date_added": "2015-12-15"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/app/student/2/",
        "id": 2,
        "title": "mr",
        "name": "student2",
        "address": "somewhere",
        "city": "Delhi",
        "tests": [
            {
                "test_name": "English",
                "section_1": "34",
                "section_2": "65",
                "date_added": "2015-12-15"
            }
        ]
    }
   ]
 }
```

I have another app in the same project the uses this data using something like this -

```
def Peoplelist(request):
    data= requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/app/students/').json()
    send_list = []
    for i in range(2):
        send_list.append(data['results'][i]['name'])
    context = RequestContext(request, {
    'send_list': send_list,
})
return render_to_response('taskmanager/numbers.html', context)
```

which creates a list of the student names.

I want to display a list of student names depending on the city name and then click on the names to view the student and test details. Can't figure out how to do that. Can someone suggest a way?Thanks.

```
models.py
class Test(models.Model):
    date_added = models.DateField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
    test_name = models.CharField(max_length=200,default='',blank=False)
    section_1 = models.CharField(max_length=100,default='') 
    section_2 = models.CharField(max_length=100,default='') 

    def __str__(self):
        return self.test_name

class Person(models.Model):
    tests = models.ManyToManyField(Test)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=3,default="mr",blank=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50,default='',blank=False)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200,default='',blank=False)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100,default='',blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

serializers.py
class TestSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Test
        fields = ('test_name','section_1','section_2','date_added')

class PersonSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    tests = TestSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = ('id','title', 'name', 'address', 'city','tests')

numbers.html

{% extends "index.html" %}
{% block names %}
{% for list in send_list %}
    <a href="/"><p>{{list}}</p></a>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

******************************EDIT*************************

```
models.py

class City(models.Model):
   city_name=models.CharField(max_length=100,default='',blank=False)

   def __str__(self):
      return self.city_name
class Person(models.Model):
   tests = models.ManyToManyField(Test)
   title = models.CharField(max_length=3,default="mr",blank=False)
   name = models.CharField(max_length=50,default='',blank=False)
   address = models.CharField(max_length=200,default='',blank=False)
   city = models.CharField(max_length=100,default='',blank=False)
```

`views.py`

```
class StudentList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Person.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PersonSerializer


class CityList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = City.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CitySerializer

class CityDetail(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    city = City.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CitySerializer

class StudentDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Student.objects.all()
    serializer_class = StudentSerializer
```

Comment: Can you share your models.py and serializers.py?

Comment: @DhiaTN added now. Thanks.

Comment: Please show your template. What have you got so far?

Comment: @RohitJain Using the view I have a shown above, I only have the list of names.

Comment: @SaketMishra Yeah, but how are you using the context data in `numbers.html` template? You said, you want to show student details on click. How you want that details? In separate page, pop up, or same page? Do you need ajax here? We need to see template file here for any help.

Comment: @RohitJain I need something like this. There is a list of cities.Once you click on any city, you go to a page which has all the students in that city. And on clicking the student name you go to a page with all the details of the student+ test details. I'll add my template file but so far it only has a list of names. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So basically you need 3 different APIs:

- `/cities/` - Gives you list of cities.
- `/cities/<pk>/students` - Gives you list of students in given city.
- `/students/<pk>/` - Gives details of Student with id `pk`.

So, that single API is not going to handle all 3 pages you want.

You'll need 3 template views:

```
def cities(request):
    data = requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/app/cities/').json()
    context = RequestContext(request, {
        'cities': data.cities,
    })
    return render_to_response('taskmanager/cities.html', context)

def Peoplelist(request, pk):
    data = requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/app/cities/' + pk + '/students/').json()
    context = RequestContext(request, {
        'students': data.students,
    })
    # Better rename this one to students.html
    return render_to_response('taskmanager/numbers.html', context)

def student_details(request, pk):
    data = requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/app/students/' + pk).json()
    context = RequestContext(request, {
        'student': data.student,
    })
    return render_to_response('taskmanager/student_detail.html', context)
```

Configure the urls for these views. Now the templates would be like:

### cities.html:

```
{% extends "index.html" %}
{% block names %}
{% for city in cities %}
    <a href="{% url 'student_list' city.id %}"><p>{{city.name}}</p></a>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

### students.html:

```
{% extends "index.html" %}
{% block names %}
{% for student in students %}
    <a href="{% url 'student_detail' student.id %}"><p>{{student.name}}</p></a>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

### student_detail.html:

```
{% extends "index.html" %}
{% block names %}
{{ student.name }}
<table>
    <tr>
    <th>Test Name</th>
    <th>Section 1</th>
    <th>Section 2</th>
    <th>Date Added</th>
    </tr>
{% for test in student.tests %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ test.test_name }}</td>
        <td>{{ test.section_1 }}</td>
        <td>{{ test.section_2 }}</td>
        <td>{{ test.date_added }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
{% endblock %}
```

---

Modification in models:

Since you've now a `City` model, you can change the `city` field to `ForeignKey` in `Person` model. Also, let's rename `Person` to `Student`:

```
class Student(models.Model):
   # Removing the tests field. Rather add `student` field in `Test` model
   # tests = models.ManyToManyField(Test)
   title = models.CharField(max_length=3,default="mr",blank=False)
   name = models.CharField(max_length=50,default='',blank=False)
   address = models.CharField(max_length=200,default='',blank=False)
   city = models.ForeignKey(City)
```

then change the `Test` model:

```
class Test(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey(Student)
    date_added = models.DateField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
    test_name = models.CharField(max_length=200,default='',blank=False)
    section_1 = models.CharField(max_length=100,default='') 
    section_2 = models.CharField(max_length=100,default='') 

    def __str__(self):
        return self.test_name
```

For views:

- `/cities/` - For this `CityList` view in your code is fine.
- `/cities/<pk>/students/` - For this, change your `StudentList` view like this:

  ```
  class StudentList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
      serializer_class = PersonSerializer

      def get_queryset(self):
          city = City.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs.get('pk', None))
          students = Student.objects.filter(city=city)
          return students
  ```

And then for last one:

- `/students/<pk>/` - `StudentDetail` view would be like:

  ```
  class StudentDetail(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
      serializer_class = PersonSerializer

      def get_object(self):
          student_id = self.kwargs.get('pk', None)
          return Student.objects.get(pk=student_id)
  ```

Now for serializers, change your `PersonSerializer` to this one:

```
class StudentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    test_set = TestSerializer(many=True, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = ('id','title', 'name', 'address', 'city', 'test_set')
```

Comment: Can you give me an idea of how the models.py will be for the relationship between cities and students and how it will be serialized for the three api's you've mentioned.Stuck on it for hours.Thanks

Comment: @SaketMishra `Student` model will have a `ForeignKey` field to `City` model. So, for a given `City` object, you can get students as - `city.student_set.all()` - that gives you result for second API I wrote there. And then for 3rd API - you just return the `Student` object for the given primary key.

Comment: Also, `Student` to `Test` should be a `OneToManyField` instead of `ManyToManyField`. One Test score cannot be assigned to 2 different Students. Since `OneToManyField` doesn't exist, that means have a `ForeignKey` to `Student` in `Test` model.

Comment: I've got the first and the third part but for the second api in `views.py` I'm using `class CityDetail(generics.ListCreateAPIView):`.How do I add only the list of students in that city to the queryset? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @SaketMishra: I see that you don't have a `City` model, rather have `city_name` in `Student` model. Have you added `City` reference in `Student` model? as `ForeignKey`? If that is the case, then for given `pk`, in second API, you get the city as - `City.objects.get(pk=pk)`, and then `city.student_set.all()` will get you students.

Comment: I have edited the code to add my current models.py and views.py. Could you please have a look.

Comment: @SaketMishra I've updated my answer. See if you get an idea of what changes needs to be done.

Answer (score 1):

*If I correctly understand, you want to have **hyperlink** for students in your api response. Inorder to this add the following in **serializer.py***:

```
class StudentByCityField(serializers.RelatedField):
    def to_representation(self, city):
        student_list = self.objects.filter(city=city)
        link_list = list()
        append_link = link_list.append
        for student in student_list:
            append_link("/app/students/%s" % student.name)
        return link_list

class PersonByCitySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    city_name = StudentByCityField(source='city', read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Test
        fields = ('city_name',)
```

*But in case you want to do this HTML side this will be trivial*

1. **views.py**

```js
def get_cities(request):
    pesrons = Person.objects.all()
    pesrons.query.group_by = ['city']
    city_set = set([i.city for i in persons])
    context = RequestContext(request, {
        'city_list': list(city_set),
    })
    return render_to_response('cities.html', context)

def get_students_by_city(request, city):
    student_list = Person.objects.filter(city=city)
    context = RequestContext(request, {
        'students': student_list,
    })
    # Better rename this one to students.html
    return render_to_response('students_by_city.html', context)

def get_student_details(request, id):
    student = Person.objects.get(id=id)
    context = RequestContext(request, {
        'student': student,
    })
    return render_to_response('student_detail.html', context)
```

2. **templates**

**cities.html**

```html
    {% extends "index.html" %}
    {% block names %}
    <ul>
    {% for city in city_list %}
        <li><a href="{% url 'student_by_city' city.name %}">
        {{city.name}}
        </a></li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    {% endblock %}
```

**students_by_city.html**

```html
{% extends "index.html" %}
{% block names %}
<ul>
{% for student in student_list %}
    <li><a href="{% url 'student_detail' student.id %}"><p>{{student.name}}</p></a></li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endblock %}
```

**student_detail.html**

```html
{% extends "index.html" %}
{% block names %}

   <!-- Display here your data as you like -->

{% endblock %}
```

3. **urls.py**

```js
urlpatterns = patterns('',

    url(r'^app/cities/$', views.get_cities, name="participant-register"), 
    url(r'^app/students/(?P<id>\d+)$', views.get_student_by_city, name="student_by_city"),
    url(r'^app/student/(?P<city>\w+/$', views.get_student_detail, name="student_detail"),                       
)
```

Comment: the following statement returns an error - `>>> city_list = [i.city for i in city_qs]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'Query' object is not iterable
`

Comment: Ah right I updated the code, It was a typo (wrong variable name) :p

Comment: Also, in every view, the `Person.objects` function is just returning the name of the string like so `[<Student: student1>]` and not a dictionary and when I try to access student_list.name or student_list.id it just throws the error `AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'name'` and likewise. And since no id, even the regex is throwing an error for no reverse match?

Comment: you should follow the example, of course **student_list** is list of object `[<Student: student1>]`, you have to apply llike in the exemple `for student in student_list` then you can access the student.name, student.id etc.
Solution is correct, it's working and I tested it, you need just to follow the example carefully.